# loading TextAsset from file and unable to compare

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I am loading TextAsset from resources which is dictionary words and added to List and i want to compare user input word with list whether list contains user input word or not? i have tried many methods but none is working, result is negative. can any one help me out to find out?

```
public TextAsset txt;
public List<string> words;

    void Awake()
    {
        words = new List<string>();
        txt = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("words");

        words = TextAssetExtensionMethods.TextAssetToList(txt);
    }

    public void Search()
    {

        Debug.Log(inputField.text);
        Debug.Log(words.Contains(inputField.text));

        Debug.Log(words.FindAll(s => s.Contains(inputField.text)));
        Debug.Log(words.FindAll(s => s.IndexOf(inputField.text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0));

        if (words.Contains(inputField.text, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) {
           Debug.Log("Contains");    
        } else{
            Debug.Log("not");    
        }    
    }

public static class TextAssetExtensionMethods {
        public static List<string> TextAssetToList(this TextAsset ta) {
            return new List<string>(ta.text.Split('\n'));
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: does "words" contain what you expected? what happens if you do String search = inputField.text, and then replace all the occurances of inputField.text with search?

Comment: yes words contains data i have checked and i have tried
String search = inputField.text;
Debug.Log(words.Contains(search));
Debug.Log( words.Any(s => s.Equals(search, StringComparison.Ordinal)));
but returns false.

Comment: Can you debug and show what the list of words looks like?

Comment: check my edits i have added image what words contains.

Comment: Are you sure your list was segmented by \n and not \r\n ?

Comment: yes, you can check file here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words.txt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192755/discussion-between-gaurang-and-bugfinder).

Comment: You are using th extension method "wrong" btw. You could simply do `words = txt.TextAssetToList();` The `words = new List<string>();` is redundant.

Comment: Can you also add what user Input you test? The `words.Contains(...)` version only matches if the input is an exact match with one of the elements. What is the output for the two log lines using `FindAll`?

Comment: Well after downloading your file, and putting some stuff in to recreate this.. Works for me.

Comment: @BugFinder I guess problem might be that we don't know yet what OP enters as Input ...

Comment: No but without reading the word list, I put in the word "decide" and .. tada it finds it.

Comment: @BugFinder but currently it probably wouldn't if you enter `dec` only .. at least not for the `if` block

Comment: Well it found decide in a whole range of other words indeed, it changes the result, in the first contains fails because dec is not a word, however the other 3 tests produce correct results.(it returned dec, false (1657 words), (1703 words), contains)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you have created an extension method for TextAsset class but now, when you have it, you should use it like this (calling own method on TextAsset instance):

```
words = txt.TextAssetToList();
```

instad of:

```
words = TextAssetExtensionMethods.TextAssetToList(txt);
```

Now, one of possible issues you might have here is leaving spaces in your strings,
just trim out your entries:

```
Array.ConvertAll(ta.text.Split(','), p => p.Trim()).ToList(); //LINQ used
```

assuming your words are separated by comma

Comment: I don't think this is the case .. seems to me OP enters e.g. `a` and expected to get a list of all entries containing an `a`.

Comment: thanks. problem is related to space. solved using Trim()

Comment: Extension methods are syntactic sugar, if someone wants to use it like a static method, they can. That's why it isn't a compiler error.